# Substitute ratio when using butter instead of shortening

Tags: baking, substitutions

How much butter should be used to use as a substitute for 1/2 cup of shortening for a banana nut bread recipe?  I don't have any shortening on hand.

Answer (score 4):

1/2 cup of shortening is 110 g, while 1/2 cup of butter is 114 g. Also, butter is only 82% fat. So if you want to be precise, use 134 g of butter: (100/82)*110 = 134. You may want to reduce the liquid by 24 g in this case.

If you don't care for precision, you can also substitute 1:1 and use 1/2 cup of butter. Most recipes for quickbreads are flexible enough for that, and you are changing the texture anyway by substituting a fat with a different melting profile.

Comment: Isn't the rest of the butter solids, rather than liquids (the 24g you're talking about)?

Comment: @data no, it's water or whey. Butter is an emulsion. A very small part of it is milk protein.

Comment: Here's a link for people wondering about moisture/fat/milk solid contents of butter, like me: http://www.sfgate.com/recipes/article/When-Put-to-the-Test-Here-s-How-Butter-Brands-3236719.php#photo-2380112

Thanks @rumtscho

Answer (score -4):

Ratio: 1 cup of crisco = 1/2 cup of butter or margarine

So, in your recipe is 1/4 of butter.

The link where I originally found the ratio is in the edit history (removed because the site is now redirecting to spam).

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you give sources for your claim? To me, this sounds way off, if deviating at all, I'd use *more* butter due to lesser fat content.

Comment: Not only is the information given dubious, but the supposed link redirects me to a site selling gift cards.

Comment: @Iain It's just that the blog's been hacked. If the owner is still active, it may get fixed. The author definitely didn't link to spam originally.